# How can I check if two array are same

Tags: php, arrays, compare

This is my array

```
[51] => Array
    (
        [171] => 34
        [170] => Adult
        [168] => 32
        [quantity] => 1
    )

[52] => Array
    (
        [171] => 34
        [170] => Adult
        [168] => 32
        [quantity] => 1
    )
```

Now if all the keys and value except quantity are same then the quantity will be added.

ex:

```
 [51] => Array
    (
        [171] => 34
        [170] => Adult
        [168] => 32
        [quantity] => 2
    )
```

Is there any way to search with dynamic keys.
Please help.

Comment: two foreach, or copy+remove quantity+compare

Comment: You need an loop to check

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that

```
$arr1 = Array(
    171 => 34
    170 => Adult
    168 => 32
    'quantity' => 1
);

$arr2 = Array(
    171 => 34
    170 => Adult
    168 => 32
    'quantity' => 1
);
```

you could do the following:

```
$tmp1 = $arr1;
unset($tmp1['quantity']);

$tmp2 = $arr2;
unset($tmp2['quantity']);

if($tmp1 == $tmp2) {
  // do what you like
}
```

when you do `$tmp1 == $tmp2` it compares the two arrays by key and value, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

> $a == $b TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs.
>
> $a === $b TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs in the same order and
>   of the same types.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_diff_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) function ... it checks array based on key

```
   <?php
      $array1 = array("a" => "green", "b" => "brown", "c" => "blue", "red");
      $array2 = array("a" => "green", "yellow", "red");
      $result = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);
      print_r($result);
    ?>
```